# Second text in Memory game is not displayed(Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my first time post a question, so do let me know anything else is required
I have been trying to create Memory game using Tkinter, please find my code below

```
from tkinter import Tk , Button , DISABLED, NORMAL
import time
import random

global texts
texts = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
random.shuffle(texts)
print(texts)


global symbols
first = True

win = Tk()
win.title("Flipping Tiles")
win.resizable(0,0)


def action(x,y):
    print(x,y)
    global first
    global first_text
    global firsti
    global firstj

    
    if first:
        print("first")
        print(symbols[x][y])
        first = False
        firsti = x
        firstj = y
        button = Button (win,text = symbols[x][y] , height = 5, width = 7 )
        first_text = symbols[x][y]
        button.grid(row=x,column=y)

    

    elif (firsti,firstj) == (x,y):
        print("same")
        pass
  

    else:
        print("second")
        print(symbols[x][y])
        first = True

        button = Button (win,text = symbols[x][y] , height = 5, width = 7 )
        button.grid(row=x,column=y)          


        if first_text == symbols[x][y]:
            print("disable part")
            button = Button (win,text = symbols[firsti][firstj] , height = 5, width = 7, state = DISABLED )
            button.grid(row=firsti,column=firstj)
            button = Button (win,text = symbols[x][y] , height = 5, width = 7, state = DISABLED )
            button.grid(row=x,column=y)    
            
        else:
            time.sleep(3)   
            print("plain part")
  
            button = Button (win,text = " " , height = 5, width = 7)
            button.grid(row=firsti,column=firstj)
            button = Button (win,text = " ", height = 5, width = 7)
            button.grid(row=x,column=y)
            
    
        
k = 0
symbols = []
for x in range(4):
    symbols.append([])
    for y in range(4):
        button = Button (win, command = lambda x=x , y=y: action(x,y), height = 5, width = 7 )
        button.grid(row=x,column=y)
        symbols[x].append(texts[k])
        k+=1

win.mainloop()
```

According my observations, everything else is working fine except displaying of second symbol(text)
can you please help me know what is causing the problem

Thank you!

Comment: just so You know You can change button text using `btn_name.config(name='name')`

Comment: also don't put `time.sleep()` because it freezes the whole script, better use [`after()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-after-method-in-tkinter/)

Comment: also it seems that You can't choose a button that was chose before, because text doesn't appear, I would suggest that You create buttons in a loop and assign them to the grid at the beginning and just change their text

Comment: 1. can we change state of Tkinter buttons using row and column value?

Comment: 2.can we know what is row and column value of button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time.sleep()` will block tkinter `mainloop()` from updating, so all the changes before `time.sleep()` will not be shown until `mainloop()` takes back the control.

Also you should update the text of the button being clicked instead of creating new button.

Below is a modified and simplified code based on yours:

```py
from tkinter import Tk , Button , DISABLED
import time
import random

texts = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
random.shuffle(texts)
print(texts)

first_button = None

win = Tk()
win.title("Flipping Tiles")
win.resizable(0,0)


def action(btn):
    global first_button
    
    btn.config(text=btn.symbol) # show the symbol for the clicked button
    btn.update_idletasks() # force update before time.sleep()

    if first_button is None:
        print("first", btn.symbol)
        first_button = btn   # save the first button clicked
    elif btn is first_button:
        print("same")  # ignore same button click
    else:
        print("second", btn.symbol)
        if first_button.symbol == btn.symbol:
            print("disable part")
            # disable matched buttons
            first_button.config(state=DISABLED, bg="#eee")
            btn.config(state=DISABLED, bg="#eee")
        else:
            time.sleep(1.5)   # use shorter delay
            print("plain part")
            # hide the symbols of clicked buttons
            first_button.config(text="")
            btn.config(text="")
        first_button = None # reset for next round


# create the buttons
buttons = []
for i, symbol in enumerate(texts):
    button = Button(win, height=5, width=7, disabledforeground="black")
    button.config(command=lambda btn=button: action(btn))
    button.grid(row=i//4, column=i%4)
    button.symbol = symbol
    buttons.append(button)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: This code worked as excepted, thank you so much
.I learnt different ways of configuring buttons and using after() func

Answer (score 0):

So, this is the very immediate solution that will make text appear and then wait for around 3 seconds and then disappear, the bigger issue (didn't ask in the question tho) is that if tiles don't match they won't be clickable later:

```py
def action(x,y):
    print(x,y)
    global first
    global first_text
    global firsti
    global firstj


    if first:
        print("first")
        print(symbols[x][y])
        first = False
        firsti = x
        firstj = y
        button = Button (win,text = symbols[x][y] , height = 5, width = 7 )
        first_text = symbols[x][y]
        button.grid(row=x,column=y)



    elif (firsti,firstj) == (x,y):
        print("same")
        pass


    else:
        print("second")
        print(symbols[x][y])
        first = True

        button = Button (win,text = symbols[x][y] , height = 5, width = 7 )
        button.grid(row=x,column=y)

        for widget in win.winfo_children():
            widget.config(state=DISABLED)

        def func():
            if first_text == symbols[x][y]:
                print("disable part")
                button = Button (win,text = symbols[firsti][firstj] , height = 5, width = 7, state = DISABLED )
                button.grid(row=firsti,column=firstj)
                button = Button (win,text = symbols[x][y] , height = 5, width = 7, state = DISABLED )
                button.grid(row=x,column=y)

            else:
                print("plain part")

                button = Button (win,text = " " , height = 5, width = 7)
                button.grid(row=firsti,column=firstj)
                button = Button (win,text = " ", height = 5, width = 7)
                button.grid(row=x,column=y)

            for widget in win.winfo_children():
                widget.config(state=NORMAL)

        win.after(3000, func)
```

As You can see I defined the whole if/elif statement in the else and then called it with after so that it executes it after 3 seconds but doesn't interfere with tkinter's mainloop

As @acw1668 mentioned using after will make the buttons clickable so I added a few lines to combat this: when clicking the second button it disables all of the buttons (all widgets but they all are buttons in this case) and then when executing the `func()` at the end makes all buttons clickable again.

Comment: *"executes it after 3 seconds but doesn't interfere with tkinter's mainloop"* will create another issue: if user clicks other button within this 3 seconds, it will mess up the application flow.  So using `time.sleep()` is better in this case even though it blocks the application.

Comment: @acw1668 thanks, didn't think about that, added code to solve that issue (at least temporarily (this isn't the ideal fix but works)) (can't use sleep because then the button will never update (I think) (actually it will but it will happen in a split second and won't be noticed by user))

Comment: @Matiiss Thanks a lot for your help. I agree - "the bigger issue (didn't ask in the question tho) is that if tiles don't match they won't be clickable later:"
I faced the same issue, what is causing this problem?

Comment: @Ash I think it is because to make buttons "clear" You just put another button on top so it covers the one that can do something, I suggest putting those buttons in a list or something and just changing their text instead of placing new buttons but that You will have to do Yourself and if You face any issues You can ask a question and obviously can link it here so that I can take a look

Comment: @Matiiss thanks alot for your help. I was able write a code wherein i just change the text instead creating new button